# Evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{k}{n\choose k}, m<n$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I've found only this formula:
$\sum_{j=k}^{n} \binom{n}{j} (-1)^j = (-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k-1}$;

But it seems useless. Please help.

Comment: You can use $\sum_0^m = \sum_0^n - \sum_{m+1}^n$.

Comment: The identity $\binom nk = \binom n{n-k}$ would also work